# PHP Namespace directory structure

Tags: php, namespaces

It is my understanding that namespaces are declared as follows : `vendor\module\classname`.

And directory structure would be:

```
/Acme
    /Module1
        /src
            /Module1
                /Class.php
```

And a valid way to instantiate the class is : `new Acme\Module1\Class();`

Are my assumptions correct?  If so,  what's the benefit of using the `src` folder?

Comment: namespaces CAN map to filesystem directory/path names, but don't HAVE to. namespaces are more to keep similarly-named-but-different modules from conflicting. e.g. you buy package 'Foo' from acme inc, but also need to use code inc.'s 'Foo' package as well. can't have two different packages with the same name, so you end up with Acme\Foo and CodeInc\Foo

Comment: if you put your code in "src" folder, then you can put the tests in the folder "tests", or examples in "examples". Is more clean in my opinion

Comment: @MarcB : did I setup the directory structure correctly?

Comment: Your directory structure is a little off. If you wanted to autoload Class(), your direction would go /src/Acme/Module1/Class.php (assuming you're using psr-0 autoloading and you defined your autoloading as  Acme": "src/"

Comment: @echochamber : So, am I correct in saying that the directory structure should be : `/Acme/Module1/src/Acme/Module1/Class.php` ?

Comment: I don't believe so. I am trying to make sure I understand what you are trying to do. Namespaces by themselves just require you to specify a namespace when when creating new instances of that class (or extending the class ect...). So if you're not using the namespaces for autoloading purposes the directory structure doesn't actually matter in relation to the namespacing. If you are autoloading, then the the src directory then it your src directory shouldn't be nested inside Acme/Module1 but still have Acme/Module1 nest nested inside it.

Comment: @ryy sorry, kinda butchered the previous comment. I updated my answer below to clarify.

Comment: Looking at your file structure - you are using Symfony2 framework. Read it's documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convention usually.

If you're using composer and you want to autoload your classes, it looks like you're trying to do PSR-0 autoloading.

So if you have `"Acme": "src/"`

Then in the same directory as your composer.json file would be a src folder, and in the src folder would be a Acme folder. All files in that folder would be namespace Acme; and all files in subdirectories of that folder would be `namespace Acme\Subdirectory;`.

In the console you need to type `composer dump-autoload` every time you make changes to the autoloading part of your composer.json file. (or for classmap autoloading, every time you add new files to directories being autoloaded.) This causes the files generated by composer to be updated. (you can find these files in the vendor/composer directory).

So if there was a src/Acme/Subdirectory/ClassName.php with a class in it named ClassName then to instantiate that class you could type `new \Acme\Subdirectory\ClassName();`

edit: so if this is your composer.json file

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Acme": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

then your directory structure would be something like this

```
/ProjectRoot
    composer.json
    /src
        /Acme
            /Module1
                Class.php
```

And you would create a new instance of your class by typing

```
new \Acme\Module1\Class();
```

Comment: if we have `vendor/module/src/ClassName.php` and want the namespace to work out so that we can call `Vendor\Module\ClassName`, how would we write the autoload definition?

Comment: @FrankForte "Vendor\Module": "vendor/module"